# Run docker commands in pipeline build by docker agent with jenkins master running as container

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-docker

I have a jenkins master running as a container in my local Windows 11 machine with docker desktop installed. My goal is to run docker commands in pipelines that are executed in cloud agents. The error I am facing is:

```
Post "http://172.23.0.2:2375/v1.24/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&rm=1&shmsize=0&t=test-image&target=&ulimits=null&version=1": dial tcp 172.23.0.2:2375: i/o timeout
```

I setup my environment following these steps.
Firstly I build my jenkins master image using the following dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.414.3-jdk17
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y lsb-release
RUN curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.asc \
  https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg
RUN echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) \
  signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.asc] \
  https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
  $(lsb_release -cs) stable" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y docker-ce-cli
USER jenkins
RUN jenkins-plugin-cli --plugins "blueocean docker-workflow"
```

Then I created a docker network:

```
docker network create jenkins
```

After I run my jenkins master container:

```
docker run --name jenkins-blueocean --restart=on-failure --detach `
  --network jenkins --env DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2376 `
  --env DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/certs/client --env DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1 `
  --volume jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home `
  --volume jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client:ro `
  --publish 8080:8080 --publish 50000:50000 myjenkins-blueocean
```

Then I logged in my jenkins installing the suggested plugins and the docker plugin.
After I run an alpine socat container:

```
docker run -d --restart=always -p 127.0.0.1:2376:2375 --network jenkins `
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock alpine/socat tcp-listen:2375,fork,reuseaddr unix-connect:/var/run/docker.sock
```

After I inspected this container to get the IP address to use as Docker Host URI in the 'Cloud docker Configuration' section of jenkins. In this section I checked the 'Enabled' and the 'Expose DOCKER_HOST' options.
[image]

Then I added a new docker agent template using 'jenkins/jnlp-agent-docker' as docker image.

[image]

Then I configured my jenkins pipeline which connects to my github repository where I pushed the following Jenkinsfile.

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    node {
      label 'docker-agent'
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        script {
          echo "Bulding docker images"
          dockerImage = docker.build("test-image", "./WebApiTest")
        }
      }
    }    
  }
}
```

Now, if I try to build my pipeline, it is able to get the Jenkinsfile from my repo, but the building of the docker image fails with the error that I posted in the beginning of this question.

Comment: Just to try, enter to the agent container and execute the docker build. Share us the result

Comment: Are you sure your socat container is still running when your job runs? Also, why use this method and not expose socket directly in Jenkins container ?

Comment: @JRichardsz I add a sleep(time:300,unit:"SECONDS") inside the pipeline in order to have enough time to enter the continer and to try the build. The error I got was 'Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?' Then I tried to update the docker host inside agent container with the command 'export DOCKER_HOST="URI"' and putting the same URI I have in the Cloud docker configuration of Jenkins. Trying again the docker build inside the agent container I get the same initial error dial tcp i/o timeout

Comment: @PierreB. Yes the socat container is still running. About the second question, I followed a tutorial on YouTube because I am new to Jenkins and I don't have a lot of experience in Docker.

Comment: I wanted to say: Enter to the agent container and perform a docker build using shell or curl. The jenkins plugins  to that but with java code

Comment: @JRichardsz I tried running the command 'curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/tar" --data-binary '@Dockerfile.tar.gz' http://172.23.0.2:2375/build?t=build_test' and I got '* connect to 172.23.0.2 port 2375 failed: Operation timed out
* Failed to connect to 172.23.0.2 port 2375 after 132754 ms: Couldn't connect to server
* Closing connection'